# How to optimize checking that elements are not present with webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with data. I need to check that table contains some data and does not contain any other data. So I need to check that table contains entries equal to some unique value.

I solved that task in two steps:

The first step is using `XPath` function `contains()` which check that table contains interesting elements.

Second step checks that table does not have other elements which are not equal search value by using `XPath` `not contains()` function.

**Example:**

```
 List <WebElement> rows = tableBody.findElements(By.xpath("//*[not(contains(td,"+ elementName + "))]"));
```

This solution is not good, because  `not contains()` function runs twice longer.

Is there other solution how to check that table has elements with search pattern and contains only them?

Comment: I think this would more optimize and correct way. It is my opinion from exp.

Comment: made title reflect comments

Comment: You can refer to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270092/best-way-to-check-that-element-is-not-present-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) link on stack overflow. Here they are discussing the same thing as mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `.findElement(By.xpath(...))` on an element, and your expression starts with `//` - webdriver would actually traverse the whole HTML tree from the very root element. If you want it to be executed in the context of the element you call `findElement` on - prepend a dot: `.//`.

#### Alternative solution

*If you are looking for speed, one out-of-the-box approach would be to get the table element source HTML and use an HTML parser (e.g. [`jsoup`](https://jsoup.org/)) to apply your requirements.* This has multiple advantages:

- you are not issuing any extra WebDriver JSON over HTTP calls, no overhead
- you are not traversing the whole tree with XPaths - you are working in the scope of your table

To get the HTML source code of the element, use `getAttribute()`:

```
tableBody.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```